# I am Using ng-table for both admin and user with different source. author data shows in admin, till refresh

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-table for admin and user with same controller, same view but loaded data with different URL, but while getting data from cache it reloads data from cache, (which I want to clear when the user logs out)

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('listArticle', ['$scope', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', 'nameService', '$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout', '$cookieStore', 'flashService', '$templateCache',
function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, nameService, $rootScope, $location, $timeout, $cookieStore, flashService, $templateCache)
{
    //$templateCache.removeAll();
    $scope.success = {};
    $scope.article = {};
    $scope.article.edit = '-';
    $scope.article.approve = '-';
    $scope.article.view = 'view';
    $scope.showAlert = true;
    flashService.displayAlertMessages();

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
            {
                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 10, // count per page
                sorting: {name: 'asc'}
            },
            {
                total: 0, // length of data
                getData: function ($defer, params)
                {
                    nameService.getData($defer, params, $scope.filter);
                },
                counts: [],
                paginationMaxBlocks: 13
            });

    $scope.$watch("filter.$", function ()
    {
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    });

}]);
```

**Service**

```
myApp.service("nameService",['$http','$filter','$cookieStore', '$rootScope', function($http, $filter, $cookieStore, $rootScope){

  function filterData(data, filter)
  {
        return $filter('filter')(data, filter);
  }

  function orderData(data, params)
  {
        return params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
  }

  function sliceData(data, params)
  {
        return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
  }

  function transformData(data,filter,params)
  {
        return sliceData( orderData( filterData(data,filter), params ), params);
  }

  var service =
  {
        cachedData:[],
        getData:function($defer, params, filter)
        {
              if(service.cachedData.length>0)
              {
                    var filteredData = filterData(service.cachedData,filter);
                    transformedData = sliceData(orderData(filteredData,params),params);
                    params.total(filteredData.length);
                    $defer.resolve(transformedData);
              }
              else
              {
                    var id = $cookieStore.get('userId');
                    if($rootScope.role == 1)
                    {
                          var url = "article/serverside/fetch-pending-list.php";
                          var data = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          var url = "article/serverside/fetch-list.php";
                          var data = {id:id};
                    }

                    $http.post(url,data)
                    .success(function(resp)
                    {
                          var i=0;
                          for(i=0; i<resp.length; i++)
                          {
                                resp[i].status = parseInt(resp[i].status);
                                resp[i].category = parseInt(resp[i].category);

                                if($rootScope.role > 1)
                                      resp[i].edit = (resp[i].status == 1)?"Edit":"";
                                else{
                                      resp[i].approve = (resp[i].status == "2")?"Approve/Reject":"";
                                }

                                var j=0;
                                var k=0;
                                for(j=0;j<statusList.length;j++){
                                      if(statusList[j]['id'] == resp[i].status)
                                            resp[i].status = statusList[j]['title'];
                                }

                                for(k=0;k<categories.length;k++){
                                      if(categories[k]['id'] == resp[i].category)
                                            resp[i].category = categories[k]['title'];
                                }
                          }
                          angular.copy(resp,service.cachedData);
                          params.total(resp.length);
                          var filteredData = $filter('filter')(resp, filter);
                          transformedData = transformData(resp,filter,params);

                          $defer.resolve(transformedData);
                    });
              }
        }
  };
  return service;
```

}]);

**Note** `if(service.cachedData.length>0)` This place same data loaded on both logins.Also like, If I save a form of data and redirect to ng-table the list is not updated, since it loads data from cache not from source.

Comment: Why don't you add user login as parameter to your data source url, as `getdata.php?login=blabla`?

Comment: I don't like to make my URL like that. Also if there is ng-table there must be something to clear these caches and I am wondering what is that?

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly clear cachedData array when user logs out so that new user will have fresh array of cached objects.

Or store the cachedData with key way. e.g.

```
cachedData=[{"user" : '123', 'data':[{}]},
"user" : '234', 'data':[{}]
]
```

this will add some complications as you will need to query cachedData based on user id.

Why not you use angular cache service which does this work automatically (i.e. it creates separate cache for different urls). https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache

Edit:To clear the cache on log out; 
If you have a auth controller (the controller that handles login and log out action). Inject the nameService in to that controller On click of logout you can simple write nameService.cachedData = [].

Comment: @Abel- If you have a auth controller (the controller that handles login and log out action). Inject the nameService in to that controller On click of logout you can simple write nameService.cachedData = [].

Comment: Fine bro, as you said I clear it in logout. Please edit your answer as per the comment. I will add bounty on that.(Still I am interested on the thing that how can I clear cache? just want to know)